# Issue with jquery when using is.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery throws a bunch of errors, when using the library is.js in my HTML. Which thus brings up problems with bootstrap. is.js has browser detection features I need to make this update compatible with all browsers. My code it formatted correctly so I dont need to share that. But here are screenshots

Without is.js included in HTML:

[image: Without is.js included in HTML]

With is.js included:

[image: With is.js included]

See the difference is that it does not show up when is.js is included. But I need it to be compatible with all browsers.

Errors it causes Jquery to throw

> jquery.js:2090 Uncaught TypeError: matchExpr[type].exec is not a function
>   jquery.js:5932 Uncaught TypeError: value.call is not a function (Recently called after I moved the location of the library above Jquery - void for now)

New order of scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/is.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

(Tosses that new error)

Old order of scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/is.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Tosses only the first error

Comment: This sounds like an error related to the order in which the files were included.

Comment: I see. So what can I do to fix this? Btw, put your answer in an.. answer.. lol and I will accept it.

Comment: It was first jquery then bootstrap then is.js then main.js (main.js is my personal file)

Comment: Let me also edit my question... I forgot to also post the errors it causes

Comment: Also added the order in which the scripts were included before and now

Comment: So you fixed it then?

Comment: No as stated moving the file caused one more error than before.

Comment: What version of is.js, what version of jQuery.js.   If you use the "non" min version what line number throws the error.    Other errors will cause later ones because the script stops parsing.   Ensure you fix the console bugs from top to bottom.   IS.js does not appear to change any native behavior so it should play nice with other libraries.